# How do you quickly know that this matrix is diagonalisable (characteristic polynomial given)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

We have matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 4 & -3\\ 
2 & 7 & -4\\ 
3 & 9 & -5
\end{pmatrix}$

The characteristic polynomial is $-(\lambda-2)^{2} \cdot (\lambda-1)=0$

Now I'd like to know a quick way to know if this matrix is diagonalisable. To be more precise, I want know that this matrix has as many eigenvalues as its own size (it's a $3 \times 3$ matrix so we need at least$3$ eigenvalues).

We see that $\lambda_{1}=2$ and $\lambda_{2}=1$ are eigenvalues. But how do I know without further long calculation that $\lambda_{1}=2$ is a double eigenvalue? I only know it because I did further calculations (polynomial long division) but how can I know it without wasting more time?

Comment: If you're not allowed to do "further calculation", what are you allowed to do?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'm allowed to do so but I want avoid it because in an exam I haven't as much time. I should have said "avoid long calculations".

Comment: Given that the multiplicity of the eigenvalue $2$ is $2$, in order to know if this matrix is diagonalisable, you'll have to check that the dimension of $ker(A - 2 I_2)$ is $2$.

Comment: If you prefer, you can check that the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $(\lambda-2)(\lambda - 1)$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes but I believe you still have to check whether the eigenvectors are linearly independent

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm asking for a short way to know that eigenvalue $\lambda_{1}=2$ is a double eigenvalue. I only know it because I used polynomial long division. I want know how to know it without using it, and without using other long / complicated / time consuming steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that there's a simple test that requires really little further computation. If you want to check if $\lambda$ is a double eigenvalue of $A$, then it is sufficient to see if $A-\lambda I$ has rank $n-2$.

In your case, if $A-2I$ has rank 1, and rank 1 matrices are really simple, since all the columns are multiples of each other.

$$
A - 2I=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 4 & -3\\ 
2 & 5 & -4\\ 
3 & 9 & -7
\end{pmatrix}
$$
In this case,  2 isn't a double eigenvalue, since the first and second column are not multiple of each other, so this matrix has rank 2 or more.